# flip function in JS ES6

Tags: facebook, immutable.js

I am using the following code(picked from facebook's immutable.js page):

```
    Immutable.Seq({a:1, b:1, c:1})
  .flip().map(key => key.toUpperCase()).flip().toObject();
```

I am trying to find where the flip() function is defined. 
 Checking the properties of Seq object and then after applying flip() to Seq object, it returns:

```
Seq [ '_object', '_keys', 'size' ]

Seq flip [ '_iter',
  'size',
  'flip',
  'reverse',
  'has',
  'includes',
  'cacheResult',
  '__iterateUncached',
  '__iteratorUncached' ]
```

I am guessing it is a part of the immutable library. lodash has a similar function but it's not the same.

Vikram

Comment: Are you asking where it exists within the returned object, or where it is in the library?

Comment: I am actually trying to figure out what it returns. So, I'm looking for some documentation for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
mixin(KeyedIterable, {

  // ### More sequential methods

  flip() {
    return reify(this, flipFactory(this));
  },
```

https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/a18350f595fcb33cd6d9680be451111d1c196c1f/src/IterableImpl.js#L494

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection.Keyed for documentation.

It flips the keys and values so {a: 'x', b: 'y'} becomes {x: 'a', y: 'b'}